# Join filtered map values

Tags: java, java-8

I have a static map as following :

```
private static final Map<String, String> queries;
static {
    Map<String, String> tmpMap = new HashMap<>();
    tmpMap.put("USER_WITHOUT_ROLE_QUERY","...");
    tmpMap.put("PROFIL_WITHOUT_ROLE_QUERY","...");
    //Removed code for readability 
    queries = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tmpMap);
}
```

And two String arrays as following:

- The `String[] typeFilter` can contain a combination of these values :
  ["WITHOUT_PROFIL", "WITHOUT_ROLE", "WITHOUT_USER"];
- The `String[] elementFilter` can contain a combination of these values : ["PROFIL",
  "ROLE", "UTILISATEUR"];

What I want to do is depending on the values in `typeFilter` and `elementFilter` to filter the `queries` map and join the values of the filtered map using `" UNION "`.

For example if `typeFilter` contains `"WITHOUT_ROLE"` and `elementFilter` contains `"PROFIL"` and `"USER"` the filtered map will only contain `PROFIL_WITHOUT_ROLE_QUERY` and `USER_WITHOUT_ROLE_QUERY` entries, thus, the result will be : `queries.get("PROFIL_WITHOUT_ROLE_QUERY") + " UNION " + queries.get("USER_WITHOUT_ROLE_QUERY")`.

**This is what I tried :**

```
// Filter queries map
List<String> queriesMapKeys = new ArrayList<>();
for (String element : elementFilter) {
    for (String type : typeFilter) {
        queriesMapKeys.add(queries.get(element + "_" + type + "_QUERY"));
    }
}
String[] queriesToJoin = queries.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> queriesMapKeys.contains(e.getKey())).collect(// I'm stuck here :-/);

String sqlQuery = String.join(" UNION ", queriesToJoin);
```

How can I solve this ? And is there a better way to do the above code?

Comment: It seems you simply want to get values for a collection of keys, do I understand it correctly?

Comment: are you looking for String[] queriesToJoin = queries.... .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0]);

Comment: @lexicore yes indeed, and it would be nice if there is a possibility to merge the first nested loop with the code where I filter the map.

Comment: I think it's OK that you precomute query names you want to filter for. But better use a `Set` like a `HashSet` for it.

Comment: @SEY_91, there's actually just a `stream.toArray(String[]::new)`.

Comment: have you got answer @IchigoKurosaki?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

```
List<String> queriesToJoin = queries.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> queriesMapKeys.contains(e.getKey())).collect(Collectors.toList());

String sqlQuery = String.join(" UNION ", queriesToJoin);
```

Comment: the `queriesToJoin` in this case id of type  `List<Map.Entry<String,String>>` and not `List<String>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use streams. You can just use a `StringJoiner` class:

```
import java.util.StringJoiner;

<...>
StringJoiner builder = new StringJoiner(" UNION ");
for (String element : elementFilter) {
  for (String type : typeFilter) {
    String key = element + "_" + type + "_QUERY";
    if (queries.containsKey(key)) {
      builder.add(queries.get(key));
    }
  }
}

String sqlQuery = builder.toString();
```

Trivia: the `StringJoiner` class is what is used internally when you execute `String::join` or collect from a `Stream` using `Collectors.joining`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you simply want to get values for a collection of keys from your map. This would be something along the lines:

```
 List<String> queriesToJoin = queries
     .entrySet()
     .stream()
     .filter(e -> queriesMapKeys.contains(e.getKey()))
     .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You also ask for a better way to implement this.

You use formatted string to model certain properties of your queries and filters. What you could try instead is that you use classes or predicates to do this.

For instance instead of using strings as keys/names of queries, consider using enums.

```
 public enum QueryId {
     USER_WITHOUT_ROLE_QUERY(USER, WITHOUT_ROLE),
     PROFIL_WITHOUT_ROLE_QUERY(PROFIL, WITHOUT_ROLE);
     QueryId(TargetElement element, QueryType type) {...}
     public TargetElement getElement() {...}
     public QueryType getQueryType() {...}
 }
```

You could then filter with predicates which use `QueryId.getElement()` or `QueryId.getQueryType()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if you want  to merge the first nested loop with the code where you filter the map

```
String[] queriesToJoin =  Arrays.asList(elementFilter)
        .stream()
        .flatMap(f -> Arrays.asList(typeFilter)
                .stream()
                .map(s -> f + "_" + s + "_QUERY"))
        .filter(t -> queries.containsKey(t))
        .map(t -> queries.get(t))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String [0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
// Filter queries map
List<String> queriesMapKeys = new ArrayList<>();
for (String element : elementFilter) {
    for (String type : typeFilter) {
        queriesMapKeys.add(queries.get(element + "_" + type + "_QUERY"));
    }
}
```

you are already querying the map and adding the result of `get` to the `queriesMapKeys` list. If a key is not in the map, `null` references will appear in the list. The keys are not available in that list. So performing another stream operation trying to match the list with the map keys like

```
String[] queriesToJoin = queries.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> queriesMapKeys.contains(e.getKey())) …
```

can’t work at all.

But it wouldn’t be necessary anyway. You only have to handle the potential `null` values. Either:

```
queriesMapKeys.removeIf(Objects::isNull);
String sqlQuery = String.join(" UNION ", queriesMapKeys);
```

or

```
String sqlQuery = queriesMapKeys.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" UNION "));
```

The latter could be merged with a preceding stream operation replacing the nested loops creating the `queriesMapKeys`:

```
String sqlQuery = Arrays.stream(elementFilter)
    .flatMap(element -> Arrays.stream(typeFilter)
        .map(type -> queries.get(element + "_" + type + "_QUERY")))                
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" UNION "));
```